# Running regression in MATLAB using glmfit - I get 7 Betas even though I only have 6 regressors

Tags: matlab

I am trying to run a multiple regression in MATLAB using the following code:

```
Regressors_0 = [Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6];

[~,~,stats_0] = glmfit(Regressors,Y, 'normal');

Betas_0 = getfield(stats_0, 'beta');

p_0= getfield(stats_0, 'p');

t_0 = getfield(stats_0, 't');
```

Where Regressors_0 is a matrix 6x1919 and where Y is a vector 1x1919. My first beta is not zero, but my first p is 0 and my first t is around 93. For betas, ps and ts I get 3 vectors all of which are 1x7. I am really at loss where the issue is. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

One of the parameters to `glmfit()` is (from the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/glmfit.html)):

> 'constant' - specify as 'on' (the default) to include a constant term
>   in the model, or 'off' to omit it.  The coefficient of the constant
>   term is the first element of B.

The constant term is 'on' be default, which adds the additional element to `Betas_0`.